# Thousands separator formatting with Databinding

Tags: android, android-resources, number-formatting, android-databinding

I have a ViewModel that looks like this:

```
public class OrderViewModel {
    double price = 23748.89;
}
```

and a layout that I bind the OrderViewModel to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="order"
            type="com.example.viewmodel.OrderViewModel"/>

    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{@string/price_format(order.price)}"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

The formatting string that is used looks like this:

```
<string name="price_format">%+.2f $</string>
```

which nicely adds the `$` sign and reduces the float representation to 2 decimals.

Outcome looks like

> 1234.89

Now I want to replace the decimal point with a comma and add a thousands separator, making my price look like

> 1.234,89

Can I do this solely with my XML formatting string or do I have to do the formatting in the java code (my ViewModel)?

Comment: Can you replace your format string with `%,.2f $` and try again? Hopefully will work.

Comment: @kha Thanks, this adds a thousands separator, but it's the other way round, with a comma as a thousands separator and a colon as the decimal separator.

Comment: @kha Your fist suggestion actually works, given the device has set it's Locale to German (propably other european Locales too). The formatting is then done according to the Locale which is 1.234,89 for german. 
If you give this (including the Locale gotcha) as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this format string:

```
%,.2f $
```

According to your own findings:

> Depending on the Locale of the device (in this case, German ), the
>   desired formatting should be automatically applied.

For German locale, this would be `1.234,89 $` whereas for UK, it would be `1,234.89 &`